# How to group a C# list when being displayed in html page

Tags: c#, html

```
string flowerList = string.Empty;
foreach (var flower in Plants.Where(x => x.Status == PlantStatus.Active))
{
    flowerList = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(flowerList)
                 ? "<li>" + flower.Colour + " " + flower.Priority + " " + flower.Category + "</li>"
                 : flowerList + "<li>" + flower.Colour + " " + flower.Priority + " " + flower.Category+ "</li>" ;
}
```

I have the above code to display a C# list data data in a html page. How can i group my `flowerList` html out put by `flower.Category`.

For each Category, I would wish to have `flower.Category` as the group header and then under it list the related records.

Comment: You're already using LINQ. Have you tried the `GroupBy` operation? Don't put the query in the `foreach` clause though. It's already hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

The code is already using LINQ. Grouping in LINQ is performed by the `GroupBy` operator. It's not a good idea to put the query in the `foreach` clause though, even for simple queries. Modifying it becomes a lot harder.

This snippet groups by category and then generates the HTML string. Instead of concatenating strings though it uses a StringBuilder to avoid creating temporary strings.

```
var categories=Plants.Where(x => x.Status == PlantStatus.Active)
                 .GroupBy(x=>x.Category);

var builder=new StringBuilder();
foreach(var category n categories)
{
    builder.AppendFormat("<div>\n<h1>{0}</h1>\n", category.Key);
    foreach(var flower in category)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("<li>{0} {1}</li>\n", 
                           flower.Colour, 
                           flower.Priority);
    }
    builder.AppendLine("</div>");
}

var html=builder.ToString();
```

**Template Engines**

Generating strings like this works only for simple HTML though. Even this code is becoming hard to maintain. In such cases it's better to use a template engine like Visual Studio's T4 or the more modern [Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban) or [Handlebars.NET](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net).

The following example uses Scriban

```
var template = Template.Parse(@"
  <H1>Flowers by Category</H1>
  {{ for category in Categories }}
    <div>
       <h2>{{ category.key }}</h2>
       <ul>
       {{ for flower in category }}
           <li>{{ flower.Colour }} {{ flower.Priority }}</li>
       {{ end }} 
       </ul>
    </div>
  {{ end }}
");

var html = template.Render(new { Categories = categories });
```

It's now a lot easier to understand what the output will look like, edit the template and find any errors.

There are at least two Visual Studio Code extensions that offer syntax highlighting and autocompletion for Scriban templates: [Scriban](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xoofx.scriban) and [SiteCore Scriban](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adamnaj.sitecore-scriban)

Comment: In the generated html, how can i have flower.Category displayed as the group heading instead of displaying as another column?

Comment: Add the HTML you want in the outer loop. I added an example that nests two lists. You have to decide *how* you want to display the flower data. As sections? Lists? If the template starts to become too complex you should consider using a template engine like Visual Studio's T4 or the more modern [Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban) or [Handlebars.NET](https://github.com/Handlebars-Net/Handlebars.Net).

Comment: Yes i would wish to display the flower data as sections.

Comment: I edited the answer. I also added an example for Scriban

Answer (score -2):

```cs
void Foo()
{
    var categories=Plants.Where(x => x.Status == PlantStatus.Active)
                 .GroupBy(x=>x.Category);

    var builder=new StringBuilder("<ul>");
    foreach(var plants in categories)
    {
        foreach(var plant in plants)
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("<li>{0} {1} {2}</li>\n", 
                           flower.Colour, 
                           flower.Priority, 
                           flower.Category);
        }
    }
    builder.AppendLine("</ul>");

    var html=builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow! A good practice when you answer a question and submit code, is to explain what each of the components do instead of dumping a wall of undocumented code in. Also remember that stackoverflow supports markdown in the text editor, so you should really make use of that especially when posting code!